# Wordpress widget with option in JS

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, widget, themes

I was wondering if in the JS from the code below I can add an option that can be set from the widget, when in wordpress backend, I hope you get my point.

More specifically, I need to add an option for slide duration. In the jCarousel that I am using, that duration is specified in $('.slides_widget').jcarousel , by the "auto: 5", so I must replace the "5" with the "slide_duration" option that is included in the widget below as you can see. How should I do it?

```
<?php 

/* Slides Widget */
class Slides_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function Slides_Widget() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_slides', 'description' => __('Create slides with this widget.'));
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350);
        parent::__construct('slides_widget', __('Slides_Widget'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $slide_duration = $instance['slide_duration'];
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', empty( $instance['text'] ) ? '' : $instance['text'], $instance );
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
            <div class="textwidget">
                <ul id="slides_widget" class="slides_widget">
                    <?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['slide_duration'] = absint($new_instance['slide_duration']);
        if (!$instance['slide_duration']) {
            $instance['slide_duration'] = "";
        }
        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
            $instance['text'] =  $new_instance['text'];
        else
            $instance['text'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['text']) ) );

        $instance['filter'] = isset($new_instance['filter']);
        return $instance;
    }
    function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array( 'filter' => true, 'title' => 'Create Your Slides', 'text' => '<li>Each slide must be in a "li" element, like this one.</li>
<li>Or like this one. Save it and check it.</li>' );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
        $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
        $text = esc_textarea($instance['text']);
        $slide_duration = strip_tags($instance['slide_duration']);
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></p>

        <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('slide_duration'); ?>"><?php _e('Slide Duration:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('slide_duration'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('slide_duration'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($slide_duration); ?>" />
        </p>

        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></p>     <p><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('filter'); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked(isset($instance['filter']) ? $instance['filter'] : 0); ?> />&nbsp;<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>"><?php _e('Automatically add paragraphs'); ?></label></p>
<?php
    }
}
register_widget('Slides_Widget');

function pixy_asd() {
?>  
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* Slides Widget */
    function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
    {
        carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
            carousel.startAuto(0);
        });
        carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
            carousel.startAuto(0);
        });
        carousel.clip.hover(function() {
            carousel.stopAuto();
        }, function() {
            carousel.startAuto();
        });
    };
    $('.slides_widget').jcarousel({
        auto: 5,
        wrap: 'last',
        visible: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'pixy_asd');

function pixy_slides_widget_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('pixySlidesJS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin/include/theme-slides-widget/js/slides_widget.js', array('jquery'), true);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pixySlidesCSS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin/include/theme-slides-widget/css/slides_widget.css', false, 1, 'screen' ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pixy_slides_widget_script');


?>
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to add a config option to a plug-in, than can then be used to manipulate the script?

Comment: I need something like @Gavriel did. The option is already added to the widget, as you can see above, but I don't know how to "manipulate the script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in form() add:

```
<input type="hidden" id="slide_duration" value="<?php echo $slide_duration;?>">
```

then use instead of auto: 5 this:

```
auto: $("#widgets-right #slide_duration").val()
```

What about a php solution? In pixy_asd():

```
$options = get_option('Slides_Widget');
$slide_duration = $options['slide_duration'];
?>
...
$('.slides_widget').jcarousel({
    auto: <?php echo $slide_duration;?>,
    wrap: 'last',
```

Comment: Thanks @Gavriel, this solution seems good and I have done exactly as you said, but for an unknown reason it doesn't work, the slider still works, but does not auto-scroll anymore.

Comment: can you add "alert($("#slide_duration").val())" before "$('.slides_widget').jcarousel({" line? I think I had a similar problem once: wordpress has multiple "copies" of the same html. One is the "default" one that is there even if you don't add it to the sidebar, and the second one is the one in the sidebar. The problem is that when you use id-s to get something you get it from the 1st occurance in the DOM, and that is the default one.

Comment: the alert thing does not work, when I refresh the browser it opens a popup sayin "Undefined", and the new ID $("#widgets-right #slide_duration") does not work either.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the php solution too, but still no result, it just breaks the JS code. It's weird, because I have used this php solution before, and I don't understand why it does not work with this widget.

Comment: can you post the exact code for the php solution + it's output? It should be easy to fix at least the js error.

Comment: You want me to post the php solution that I have used before? Wouldn't be easier if I send you the widget somehow? maybe this would be easier for you to fix it.

Comment: fixing the php syntax error and the js syntax error shouldn't be hard. Just copy&paste the php to the "html", and the js output to the "js" window of http://jsfiddle.net, and post here the link. I'd rather not install the plugin on my server, it's too complicated

Comment: I don't see the php solution in there

Comment: If you are reffering to the PHP solution you have posted, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/3GQtV/1/ ...

Comment: please add this as 3rd line to function pixy_asd: 'var_dump($options);' and send me the output of pixy_asd(). I'm sure that the problem is in the 1st two lines. Maybe it has to be something else instead of get_option('Slides_Widget'); Can you also try 'slides_widget' and 'widget_slides' ?

Comment: I have added the 'var_dump($options);' http://jsfiddle.net/3GQtV/2/ , and now I get this error on top of the header: 'bool(false)'.  And also tried 'slides_widget' and 'widget_slides', with the 'widget_slides' I get another error 'array(2) { [2]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(0) "" } ["_multiwidget"]=> int(1) }' instead 'bool(false)'.

Comment: so 1st of all you should use $options = get_option('widget_slides'); secondly, it doesn't have the slide_duration, so how do you want to use it???

Comment: Ok, then I will use 'widget_slides. What do you mean that it does not have the slide_duration? I have missed something? http://jsfiddle.net/3GQtV/4/

Comment: you wrote that this is what var_dump prints: 'array(2) { [2]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(0) "" } ["_multiwidget"]=> int(1) }', and there's no slide_duration in it, that's why this php solution won't work anyway. So where does slide_duration come from? I thought it's also saved in the options

Comment: I think I am getting more confuse now. The slide_duration is set in the widget, and I have checked it by adding this <?php echo $slide_duration ?> in the widget's content. Can you please tell me what should I do? I have to tell you that there are things that I don't understand regarding PHP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in widget() and form() functions you get a parameter array, and slide_duration is passed in the array, but on pixy_asd it's not passed. I thought it's a value that is saved in the widget's configuration in the DB, then we could've get it with wp_option(). But it turns out that it's not in the options. So maybe it's the 1st time, before it's saved... then change the line '$slide_duration = $options['slide_duration'];' to '$slide_duration = $options['slide_duration'] ? $options['slide_duration'] : 5;', so it'll have a default of 5, and if you save it it should get the new value

Comment: I have done so, now it gets only the default number 5, and the slide works, but the number set from  the widget's panel it's not taken into consideration, it rolls at only 5sec.

Comment: you need to fix the widget, so that it saves the options. Maybe you should ask it in another question. I haven't used this format of widget with class Slides_Widget extends WP_Widget, so I cant help in that one. When the settings are saved, this should work, if not come back, and we'll fix it

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I understand. I will let you know what was the issue.

Comment: Any idea where can I find the format of widget like you have used?

Comment: for example here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-tag-cloud/ but WP_Wodget class seems to be more advanced, if I were you I wouldn't change it to older format. Try to fix the settings in your version

Comment: Hi again @Gavriel. I have found a solution that actually works for my widget, but I am not sure if it could affect something else, or if is right like that. Actually the solution is pretty simple, I have moved the <script> from the function pixy_asd inside the widget, in function widget( $args, $instance ) {...}. See the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/68Cyx/ . As you are more experienced, can you please tell me if is wrong or something?

Comment: don't do that, since as I explained previously the widget code will appeare more than once in the html. But if that worked for you, then let's fix it this way: in widget() only add: "<script type='text/javascript'>slide_duration = <?php echo $slide_duration ?>;</script>" and in the original pixy_asd use: "auto: slide_duration", so it uses the global js variable.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but not too well, because if I add multiple slides, all are taken the setting from the last one. Actually what I have done was having the same problem.

Comment: open a separate question on that, because your code is not prepared to multiple widgets. this is what you can do with the current code: 0 or 1 widget (which will have 1 or 2 instances on the page, but the last one is the real one so it works)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try to google a bit for an answer, if I can't find anything I will post a new question. Thanks a lot for your help.